# Validar campos checkbox com Bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validação, validator

Estou tentando utilizar o Bootstrap validator nos campos checkbox, mas não sei como fazer. Tem alguma função nessa biblioteca que faça isso ou eu devo fazer a validação em JS puro?

Código:

```
<div class="form-check">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="ingles" class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" id="ingles" name="idioma" value="ingles" class="form-check-input">Inglês
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox">
     <label for="espanhol" class="form-check-label ">
     <input type="checkbox" id="espanhol" name="idioma" value="espanhol" class="form-check-input">Espanhol
     </label>
   </div>                                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pra você usar o validator do bootstrap, primeiramente, você deve ter a biblioteca js dele especificado no seu arquivo html (mas no caso, parece que você já o tem).

Após isso, você precisa especificar no seu campo `<form>` o seguinte atributo:

```
data-toggle="validator"
```

Após você especificar na tag `<form>` o atributo acima, você também deve colocar nas tag `<input>` o atributo `required` e o atributo `data-error` como por exemplo:

```
data-error="Esse item é inválido"
```

E para finalizar o uso correto do `validator`, abaixo de cada `<input>` (depois do fechamento da tag), você cria uma `div` com a class `help-block with-errors` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

Então você estará com o `validator` ativado e funcionando para cada campo que você especificar estes itens.

Vou deixar abaixo um pequeno código com os requisitos e atributos já prontos para o `validator`.

```
<script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>

<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Informe seu E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" data-error="Informe um e-mail válido." required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o `data-toggle="validator"` no `<form>`, no seu caso na `<div class="form-check">`

Pode ser feito também por `Jquery` usando `$('.form-check').validator();`